# WPF bind dictionary<string, List<Person>> to listview by group

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, dictionary

I have a class

```
class Person
{
  public string Name..get...
  public string Age...get... 
}
```

this is stored in a `Dictionary<string, List<Person>> m_PersionDict;`

I want to display this dictionary in a listview by group... group name is the key of the dictionary..

Something like:

[image]

here Male and female are the different keys in the dictionary..

Thanks...

Comment: you might want a TreeView

Comment: You'd much rather _"flatten"_ your data structure and proceed as shown [HERE](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/).

Comment: @jstreet that's going to be my last option.. If there is a way to populate a listview from a dictionary with list thru data binding.. I would take that...

Comment: @Patrick how do I add column headers to a treeview? specifically via xaml...

Comment: @HariPanicker : Also, by _"hardcoding"_ the grouping itself in your `Dictionary`, defeats the whole purpose of letting `CollectionViewSource` do it for you. If later-on you want to change the grouping, you can't : it's _"baked-in"_ in your data structure.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way of doing this, i.e. bind directly to a `Dictionary<string, List<Person>>` and apply a `PropertyGroupDescripton` to the `ICollectionView`, but you could easily transform the dictionary to a list of anonymous objects and then group by the Key property as usual:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //the dictionary
    Dictionary<string, List<Person>> m_PersionDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Person>>();
    m_PersionDict.Add("Male", new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 },
                new Person() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 }
            });
    m_PersionDict.Add("Female", new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 }
            });

    var flattened = m_PersionDict.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Select(y => new { Key = x.Key, Name = y.Name, Age = y.Age })).ToList();
    lv.ItemsSource = flattened;

    CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv.ItemsSource);
    PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Key");
    view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
}
```

This shouldn't have any real consequences and is a small price to pay.

```
<ListView Name="lv">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: var selectedItem = (dynamic)lv.SelectedItems[0];
string name= selectedItem.Name; string age= selectedItem.Age;